# can i use my blogspot address as android package name

Tags: android

can I use my Blogspot address (`example.blogspot.in`) as android package name for publishing the app to play store? is it ok with google Terms and Policies?

Comment: yes it is a valid domain name

Comment: So far I haven't read anything that violates if you use the blogspot url.

Comment: yes its possible , but since its not visible to user, what difference would it make to your app anyway ?

Comment: @Ak9637 It will be visible to user, at least in URL of google play store

Comment: ok thats a great thought on ur side,by i doubt any end user actually pay attention to links during download